# spring saml deadlock issue while refreshing metadata

Tags: spring, security, saml

We are getting the following error in production. Based on the answer to that post, I understand a fix will be available in Spring Security Saml 1.0.2 release.

[Metadata refresh deadlock (spring-security-saml)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30324200/metadata-refresh-deadlock-spring-security-saml#)

Are there any work around for this error? Are there any file system based metadata provider which will avoid the automatic refresh?

Thanks

Nara